# Sending windows configuration file to another windows pc

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-registry

Does somebody know if there is any possibilities to send to the remote user (via email/skype/ftp, etc.) a windows configuration file that configures some settings on remote desktop ? I mean, to send some sort of registry file (.reg) to user with preconfigured values, so he could run it and make changes do his computer?

What i really need is to send a preconfigured file which will enable to receive a remote desktop connection once it's executed.

This will help me out, instead of telling to a remote user what to do or where to click and what to type by telephone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you send him the settings of `Remote Desktop Connextion`?

Remote Desktop can be launched from the `Search programs or files` in the windows menu or the Run dialog (by typing `Windows + R`) by typing `mstsc`.

Then one can save and open configuration in the `Options` (little button in the left bottom corner).

Comment: Yes, it will work if i will need to send him `Connection settings`, but what i really need is to send him a configuration that will do the job by configuring necessary things in OS.
His OS do not accept remote connection, so i want to ask if there is any possibilities to turn in on within sended config ?

Comment: @aspirinemaga Ah ok. You can actually export all your register settings or only some selected keys. `Windows + R` > `regedit` and then `File > Export...`.  Though the other needs administrator rights to apply them.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what i want to do, but once i looked inside the registry i realised it's not that simple, and especially for me it looks like a maze. Is there any documentation (such as API) or something like that ? Thank you

Comment: I don't know about any API. But if you make a search on Miscrosoft's support site you will find that the registry key for remote desktop is ` HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ `.

Comment: I think it's what I need. Could yo update your answer with your last comment pls? so I could accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your are looking RDP solution over the internet and according to my research it's not possible, Because in that cases we will also need to setup router to forward RDP traffic (Default port 3389) to target host as well.

So, I suggest you to use third party application instead of RDP, Where you can create, pre-configure file, So user can download and run. I preferd [logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/) in that cases, you can give it a try,

Comment: Ok, thanks for that info, will check that out again to confirm it before accepting your answer.